# Is there any way to limit the channels created by the producer?

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

We have and application that produces messages really fast and requires ACK.

This is a silly simulation:

```java
    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory ccf() {
        var ccf = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        ccf.setPublisherConfirmType(CORRELATED);
        ccf.setPublisherReturns(true);
        return ccf;
    }


    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner run(RabbitTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            for (int i = 1; i < 10001; i++) {
                template.convertAndSend("poc", "hey");
                if (i % 1000 == 0) {
                    LOG.info("{}", i);
            }   }
        };
    }
```

This code end up creating and destroying several channels, is there any way to limit the channels that are going to be created concurrently? (blocking or enqueueing)

This is one of the channels that remain cached in the rabbit console: 127.0.0.1:54190 (509).

Answer (score 2):

See `setChannelCheckoutTimeout`.

```java
    /**
     * Sets the channel checkout timeout. When greater than 0, enables channel limiting
     * in that the {@link #channelCacheSize} becomes the total number of available channels per
     * connection rather than a simple cache size. Note that changing the {@link #channelCacheSize}
     * does not affect the limit on existing connection(s), invoke {@link #destroy()} to cause a
     * new connection to be created with the new limit.
     * <p>
     * Since 1.5.5, also applies to getting a connection when the cache mode is CONNECTION.
     * @param channelCheckoutTimeout the timeout in milliseconds; default 0 (channel limiting not enabled).
     * @since 1.4.2
     * @see #setConnectionLimit(int)
     */
    public void setChannelCheckoutTimeout(long channelCheckoutTimeout) {
```

**EDIT**

This works as expected...

```
spring.rabbitmq.cache.channel.size=2
spring.rabbitmq.cache.channel.checkout-timeout=1s
spring.rabbitmq.publisher-confirm-type=correlated
spring.rabbitmq.publisher-returns=true
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So69699961Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So69699961Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(CachingConnectionFactory cf) {
        return args -> {
            Connection conn = cf.createConnection();
            Channel chann1 = conn.createChannel(false);
            Channel chann2 = conn.createChannel(false);
            try {
                Channel chann3 = conn.createChannel(false);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            chann2.close();
            chann1.close();
            conn.close();
        };
    }

}
```

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpTimeoutException: No available channels
```

Comment: That is great! thank you so much!

Comment: I am still creating more channels than the configured number, far less than without the given config. is that possible?

Comment: I don't see how - see the edit to my answer.

Comment: I don't see how neither. I will post my actual code in your repo issues